# extracting array of objects from xml response to js

Tags: apigee

so I'm extracting variables from my xml response and trying to reformat the objects but I want to do that the most efficient way possible. so I want to load the xml array of same objects into a js array that I can cycle thru and output the new format. I found a reference to type="nodeset" when extracting the XPath but i could not find a reference to it on the documentation.

what is the best way to load the full xml objects into a js variable and cycle thru the objects and output the new format

Thanks for any help you can give me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to accomplish this is with the XMLToJSON policy, a JavaScript callout in which you can mediate your payload, and then transform back with JSONToXML if you need it.

Comment: I found response.content.asXML; that I can use on js to load the structure and access the objects inside. still need to figure out how to do cycles over all objects of the same tag

Comment: For that you can use xpath actually, if your data is consistent. If not, parsing it into a JavaScript object is still the simplest (and probably close to performant) way to go.

Answer (score 0):

For an XML array that doesn't need filtering, you can use XPATH with `type="nodeset"`, just as you described.  This allows you to pull a node and all child nodes in a particular XPATH.  As I'm sure you noticed, you can't do this by just extracting as `type="string"`. Just know that you will need to convert the extracted variable to string before you can use the XML nodes like you do every other string.  You can then do `JSON.parse` to take the string and manipulate the object like an array.  The string conversion is as simple as calling a JS callout with the following code (if someone else has a better way, I'm all ears):

```
var extractedNodeSet = context.getVariable("extractedNodeSet");
var extractedNodeSetString = String(extractedNodeSet);
```

For an XML array that needs filtering/manipulation, I recommend to use XSLT along with the trusted `<xsl:for-each select=...>` element.  This will let you set conditions on the XML array nodes, manipulate tags/data, and extract the data, all in one step.  The only concern is that this isn't a JS array, so if you absolutely must have a JS array, then you'll need to then do an XMLtoJSON and work with the data from there.

Comment: thanks for the string transformation reference for JS. that was really helpfull

Comment: for cycles I end up using a counter and a while

var i = 0;
while(folder = folders.folder[i]){
    i++;
    r.folders.push(reformatFolder(folder));
  }